A SELECT using another table's rows to create and name columns - Select every student in "Blue" class with a separate column for each subject taken
I'm struggling to know where to start on this one. I want to write a SELECT query which will return all the students in a particular class and the subjects they each take. But the subjects are stored in rows of another table and I need to somehow make them become a new column for every subject.
I have four tables:
Class Groups:



ID
Class Name
Teacher




1
Blue
Mr Smith


2
Red
Miss Brown



Students:



ID
ClassID
Last Name
First Name




1
1
Cooper
Sarah


2
2
Jones
John


3
1
Moody
Claire


4
1
Baggins
Frodo



Classes:



ID
Class




1
Geography


2
Science


3
English


4
History


5
Spanish



Class_attendees



Class ID
Student_ID




1
1


1
2


1
4


2
1


2
5


3
2


3
3


3
4


4
1


4
2


4
3



I want to write a SELECT query that shows me the timetable for Blue Class that would look like this.



Last Name
First Name
Geography
Science
English
History




Cooper
Sarah
1
1

1


Moody
Claire

1
1
1


Baggins
Frodo
1
1
1




Since no-one in Blue Class is taking Spanish I don't need a column for it.

What you're doing is contrary to how relational-databases and SQL work: one of the fundamental rules is that columns are static, the dynamism is in the rows/tuples. What you need to do is split this task up so it fits into the two layers you're working with: the data-query part (which must conform to the relational model) and the presentation part (i.e. your HTML table code or Report Generator datagrid).


I want to write a SELECT query which will return all the students in a particular class and the subjects they each take. But the subjects are stored in rows of another table and I need to somehow make them become a new column for every subject
I want to write a SELECT query that shows me the timetable for Blue Class...

The first part is a straightforward JOIN - but the second part ("...make them become a new column" and "shows me the timetable for") is not possible in SQL nor is it supported by the relational-model that SQL is based on, because the "timetable" view you describe is not an example of relational-data (btw, the term "relational" does not refer to "relationships" or foreign-keys; please see Codd's paper I linked to).
One of the fundamental rules here (paraphrased) is that columns are static (i.e. your SQL query defines the columns directly: e.g. a, b, c in SELECT a, b c FROM d), so when dealing with data that may-or-may-not-exist (or instead, not-only exists, but has a very high cardinality) then that's all in the rows/tuples.
So your internal data representation of these undefined columns based on your not-yet-known-in-advance query results cannot have these dynamic columns, but that's okay because the job of rendering a table/data-grid with dynamic columns is best done by your presentation layer (presumably PHP to generate a HTML <table> or some Report/templating engine you're using?) - but not using only SQL.
(Yes, you can hack it to work by using Dynamic SQL but let's just not go there. There is also PIVOT/UNPIVOT, but that still requires you to know what the columns are in-advance when you write the query).
Anyway, the first part is easily done:
SELECT
    s.LastName,
    s.FirstName,
    c.ClassName
FROM
    Class_attendees AS ca
    INNER JOIN Students AS s ON ca.Student_ID = s.ID
    INNER JOIN Classes  AS c ON ca.Class_Id   = c.ID
WHERE
    s.ClassID = 1
ORDER BY
    s.LastName,
    s.FirstName,
    s.ID /* Using this as a tie-breaker if two students have the same name */,
    c.ClassName

...which will give you this:



LastName
FirstName
ClassName




Cooper
Sarah
Geography


Cooper
Sarah
Science


Cooper
Sarah
History


Moody
Claire
Science


Moody
Claire
English


Moody
Claire
History


Baggins
Frodo
Geography


Baggins
Frodo
Science


Baggins
Frodo
English



...and as said, the task of flattening this into that "timetable" view will be done by your presentation-layer and cannot be done using SQL.

...but if you don't care about de jure columns, you can still flatten the results using GROUP_CONCAT:
WITH studentClasses AS (

    SELECT
        s.ID AS StudentId,
        s.LastName,
        s.FirstName,
        c.ClassName
    FROM
        Class_attendees AS ca
        INNER JOIN Students AS s ON ca.Student_ID = s.ID
        INNER JOIN Classes  AS c ON ca.Class_Id   = c.ID
    WHERE
        s.ClassID = 1
)
SELECT
    g.LastName,
    g.FirstName,
    GROUP_CONCAT( g.ClassName ORDER BY g.ClassName SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS Classes
FROM
    studentClasses AS g
GROUP BY
    g.StudentId /* One should always prefer to GROUP BY actual keys rather than _plain ol' data_ columns; in this case, it means we avoid the pitfull of grouping distinct students that have the same name. */
    /* I assume you're using a modern version of MySQL that detects functional-dependencies in GROUP BY clauses (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html ) */
ORDER BY
    g.LastName,
    g.FirstName,
    g.StudentId


Gives you...



LastName
FirstName
Classes




Cooper
Sarah
Geography, Science, History


Moody
Claire
Science, English, History


Baggins
Frodo
Geography, Science, English




Thank you @Dai! That is a very well explained and educational answer (and also explains why I couldn't even get a start on the query!). You correctly assumed that I'm using PHP; I was so focused on trying to get the data it never occurred to me that I could just flatten! (Thanks also for editing my question to make the table formatting work. It showed fine in preview but when I posted was nonsense. For future reference where did I go wrong?).

@Amused StackOverflow's Markdown table formatting preview has always been buggy (I understand it's because the JavaScript version used for previewing is a different Markdown impl. comapred to their server-side code) - it's something that trips up everyone, including myself.

While MySQL has no PIVOT function, you could have make use of
CASE WHEN - THEN in this way: (code not tested)
SELECT
LastName
,FirstName
,CASE WHEN ca.Class_ID  = 1 THEN COUNT(ca.Class_ID) ELSE null END AS Geography
,CASE WHEN ca.Class_ID  = 2 THEN COUNT(ca.Class_ID) ELSE null END AS Science
,CASE WHEN ca.Class_ID  = 3 THEN COUNT(ca.Class_ID) ELSE null END AS English
,CASE WHEN ca.Class_ID  = 4 THEN COUNT(ca.Class_ID) ELSE null END AS History

FROM
Class_attendees ca
INNER JOIN students s ON ca.Student_ID=s.ID
INNER JOIN Class_Groups cg on s.ClassID=cg.ID

WHERE cg.Class_Name='Blue'

GROUP BY
ca.Student_ID

Class_id column in table Students has same name of Class ID in Class_attendees table but two different meanings, you should choose better naming.
Info in Classes tables is replicated in CASE WHEN instructions
